# Keras error : Expected to see 1 array

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I got the following error when I tried to train an MLP model in keras(I am using keras version `1.2.2`)

> Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you
>   are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected
>   to see 1 arrays but instead got the following list of 12859 arrays:

This is the summary of the model

```
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                     Output Shape          Param #     Connected to
====================================================================================================
dense_1 (Dense)                  (None, 20)            4020        dense_input_1[0][0]
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)                  (None, 2)             42          dense_1[0][0]
====================================================================================================
Total params: 4,062
Trainable params: 4,062
Non-trainable params: 0
____________________________________________________________________________________________________
None
```

This is the first line of model

```
 model.add(Dense(20, input_shape=(200,), init='lecun_uniform', activation='tanh'))
```

For training:

```
model.fit(X,Y,nb_epoch=100,verbose=1)
```

where X is a list of elements and each element in turn is a list of 200 values.

Edit :

I also tried

```
model.add(Dense(20, input_shape=(12859,200), init='lecun_uniform', activation='tanh'))
```

but I am getting the same error

Comment: Try using the keyword `input_dim` instead: `input_dim=200` which defines the number of input nodes. The number of samples is variable then. With `input_shape` you have to specify the full shape, i.e. also the number of samples (`input_shape=(len(X), 200)`).

Comment: How about `model.fit(numpy.array(X), Y,nb_epoch=100,verbose=1)`  it seems that for some reason your `X` is not a numpy array.

Comment: Try passing a `np.array(X)` instead of a list of `np.array` to `model.fit`.

Comment: Exactly. It would be better if you provided a full code - with `X` and `Y` definition. Try to print out `type(X)`.

Comment: Thanks guys .. it seems to work with input_dim=200 , passing np.array(X).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Your error comes from the fact that your `X` for some reason wasn't transformed to a `numpy.array`. In this your `X` is treated as a list of rows and this is a reason behind your error message (that it expected one input instead of list which has a number of rows elements). Transformation:

```
X = numpy.array(X)
Y = numpy.array(Y)
```

I would check a data loading process because something might go wrong there.

**UPDATE:**

As it was mentioned in a comment - `input_shape` need to be changed to `input_dim`.

**UPDATE 2:**

In order to keep `input_shape` one should change to it to `input_shape=(200,)`.

Comment: Thank you for summarizing .. I also had to change input_shape to input_dim . Please add that to your answer :)

Comment: Done. If you want to keep `input_shape` then try `input_shape=(200,)`.

Comment: Worked for me too. Oh god! This is such a dumb error. Keras developers should've written some code to just automatically convert the array into a numpy array instead of showing this dumb error!!!

Answer (score 5):

I fixed mine by adding

> np.array

to train_X , train_Y , valid_X and valid_Y. For example,

```
model.fit(np.array(train_X),np.array(train_Y),
          batch_size=32,nb_epoch=20,
          validation_data=(np.array(valid_X),np.array(valid_Y)),
          callbacks=[early_stop])
```

I got the help from [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/4002). This approach is likely to have a slow run because all data features will have to be converted to numpy arrays and it could be a lot of work for your system.